# Android OrmLite TableUtils Create View

Tags: android, orm, sqlite, ormlite

Using OrmLite, with `TableUtils` I can create a table, that map my entity in this way

```
TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource,MyClass.class)
```

is possible to create a sql tableView?

or I must insert the sql code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select from a view, just like any table, but you can't create views.

Comment: as I suspected... but can I execute an sql instruction like "create view blablabla"?

Answer (score 1):

I tried code below with SQLite (on memory) and it seems to work fine.

```
String stmt = "CREATE VIEW viewName AS Select * FROM someTable ;";
foo.getDao().executeRawNoArgs(stmt);
```